# Advice needed on editable WinForms table with many columns, also... what is this widget?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, datagridview

I have a table with lots and lots of editable columns (clipped a bit for the question):

[image: cramped columns]

This is currently implemented in a DataGridView and is editable.  However, substituting abbreviations in the display, and the drop-downs, etc.. is all getting a bit cramped and ugly, so I'm looking for a different visual and presenting them to the team for some choices.

My Google-fu is failing me, however.

One thing that attracted my interests is this sort of model:

[image: unknown widget]

I've seen this widget throughout Visual Studio and other tools, but ... what is it?  How is it implemented?  I would assume that since it's in a few places there's a standard implementation method that MS uses, and I don't want to re-invent that wheel based on looks alone so what's it called?

I've thought about a multi-line DataGridView widget, is there one you'd recommend?

Are there other UI widgets you'd recommend for this?

The only restriction is that I need to keep this keyboard-friendly if possible.

Comment: Are you thinking about `PropertyGrid` [control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22717/Using-PropertyGrid) Maybe [VerticalGrid](https://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Vertical_Grid/) from devexpress could help

Comment: Yes!  It's a PropertyGrid.  Thank you.

Comment: An alternative to DevExpress is ComponentOne, which I use.  Both are solid, but pick the one that fits you best.

Answer (score 1):

I've used (and very much) like [ObjectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html) which is a *massive* enhancement on the winforms ListView control. It has functionality in spades and the docs are very thorough (and its open source)
I have used it on a view with over 100 columns.

I also use the `PropertyGrid` in places but its not as configurable as I'd like and some data suits better in a table format than in a property grid.